# Parse through txt files and output them in new format

Tags: ruby, sorting

I have a few txt files and I need to be able to parse through them with three different outputs:

- Output 1 – sorted by gender (females before males) then by last name ascending.
- Output 2 – sorted by birth date, ascending.
- Output 3 – sorted by last name, descending.

Here is a sample of all three text files:

pipe.txt:

```
Smith | Steve | D | M | Red | 3-3-1985
Bonk | Radek | S | M | Green | 6-3-1978
Bouillon | Francis | G | M | Blue | 6-3-1975
```

comma.txt:

```
Abercrombie, Neil, Male, Tan, 2/13/1943
Bishop, Timothy, Male, Yellow, 4/23/1967
Kelly, Sue, Female, Pink, 7/12/1959
```

space.txt:

```
Kournikova Anna F F 6-3-1975 Red
Hingis Martina M F 4-2-1979 Green
Seles Monica H F 12-2-1973 Black
```

I was able to get pipe.txt alphabetically sorted by writing this:

```
pipe = File.open('pipe.txt', 'r') 
alpha = pipe.sort { |a, b| a <=> b }
puts alpha
```

I've had no luck figuring out anything else. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First, your sample code might work, but it's not something you want to rely on.

I'd write

```
pipe = File.open('pipe.txt', 'r') 
alpha = pipe.sort { |a, b| a <=> b }
puts alpha
```

as:

```
alpha = File.readlines('pipe.txt').sort
```

The difference is that using `open` and sorting the handle leaves the file handle open. Dangling file handles can consume all the available handles on a system causing problems in long-running tasks, so get in the habit of using methods, or constructs, that automatically close files when they're done, or make sure you explicitly close the file. Using `readlines` automatically returns an array of lines AND closes the file when it's finished reading. That array is then passed to `sort`.

A bare `sort` will automatically use the same block as `{ |a, b| a <=> b }` so that's redundant and not needed.

Your code is sorting by the entire string, but that isn't really what you want. Instead, you MUST break the lines into the component columns, then sort by those. Consider this:

```
ary = [
  'a b',
  'a  b'
].sort 

ary # => ["a  b", "a b"]
```

On the surface it seems like `'a  b'` would be the same as `'a b'` or after it, but, because `' '` has a lower ASCII value than `b`, `'a  b'` ends up collating before `'a b'`:

```
' '.ord # => 32
'b'.ord # => 98
```

Looking at the actual values:

```
'a b'.chars.map(&:ord)  # => [97, 32, 98]
'a  b'.chars.map(&:ord) # => [97, 32, 32, 98]
```

So, that's why we want to split the lines into their values, to negate the effect of the delimiters.

Moving on, splitting the lines isn't necessary something you want to do in a "universal" method, though you could. And, I'm not about to write it all for you, but I'll point the way.

"comma.txt" can be parsed cleanly using the built-in [CSV](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) library. "CSV" stands for "Comma Separated Values". The documentation already has an example showing how to parse lines from a file or from a string. I'm using the string version, but you'd want to modify it to use the file version. As a starting test, this shows that we can sort sub-arrays and get the desired results:

```
text = 'a,b,c
a,a,b
a,a,a
'

require 'csv'

ary = []
CSV.parse(text) do |row|
  ary << row
end

ary.sort
# => [["a", "a", "a"], ["a", "a", "b"], ["a", "b", "c"]]
```

Now it's possible to just split the lines into the component fields and things should work:

```
text = 'Abercrombie, Neil, Male, Tan, 2/13/1943
Bishop, Timothy, Male, Yellow, 4/23/1967
Kelly, Sue, Female, Pink, 7/12/1959
'

require 'csv'

ary = []
CSV.parse(text) do |row|
  ary << row
end

ary.sort
# => [["Abercrombie", " Neil", " Male", " Tan", " 2/13/1943"],
#     ["Bishop", " Timothy", " Male", " Yellow", " 4/23/1967"],
#     ["Kelly", " Sue", " Female", " Pink", " 7/12/1959"]]
```

Note that the fields are retaining their leading spaces. You can use `strip` on the individual fields to remove leading and trailing spaces, or `map(&:strip)`. It's up to you to figure out how to do that.

Dealing with pipes.txt is almost the same, it just takes telling CSV how to interpret the columns:

```
text = 'Smith | Steve | D | M | Red | 3-3-1985
Bonk | Radek | S | M | Green | 6-3-1978
Bouillon | Francis | G | M | Blue | 6-3-1975
'

require 'csv'

ary = []
CSV.parse(text, col_sep: '|') do |row|
  ary << row
end

ary.sort
# => [["Bonk ", " Radek ", " S ", " M ", " Green ", " 6-3-1978"],
#     ["Bouillon ", " Francis ", " G ", " M ", " Blue ", " 6-3-1975"],
#     ["Smith ", " Steve ", " D ", " M ", " Red ", " 3-3-1985"]]
```

Again, the spaces are retained, only now they're trailing spaces. And, again, you get to figure out how to handle them.

Dealing with text.txt is probably the most straightforward:

```
text = 'Kournikova Anna F F 6-3-1975 Red
Hingis Martina M F 4-2-1979 Green
Seles Monica H F 12-2-1973 Black
'

ary = text.split("\n").map { |row|
  row.split
}
puts ary.map{ |r| r.join(',') }

# >> Kournikova,Anna,F,F,6-3-1975,Red
# >> Hingis,Martina,M,F,4-2-1979,Green
# >> Seles,Monica,H,F,12-2-1973,Black

ary.sort
# => [["Hingis", "Martina", "M", "F", "4-2-1979", "Green"],
#     ["Kournikova", "Anna", "F", "F", "6-3-1975", "Red"],
#     ["Seles", "Monica", "H", "F", "12-2-1973", "Black"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simplest to go with the csv format and let a library do the parsing out of the data into separate fields.

Here's an example script that shows your 3 sort orders

```
require 'csv'
require 'date'

data = CSV.parse(DATA)

SurnameIndex = 0
GenderIndex  = 2
DateIndex    = 4

puts "By gender then surname: %s" % data.sort_by.sort_by { |object| [ object[GenderIndex], object[SurnameIndex] ] }.inspect
puts "By birth date: %s" % data.sort_by.sort_by { |object| Date.strptime(object[DateIndex], '%m/%d/%Y') }.inspect
puts "By surname descending: %s" % data.sort_by.sort { |a, b| b[SurnameIndex] <=> a[SurnameIndex] }.inspect

__END__
Abercrombie,Neil,Male,Tan,2/13/1943
Bishop,Timothy,Male,Yellow,4/23/1967
Kelly,Sue,Female,Pink,7/12/1959
```

Notice the last sort has the `a` and `b` objects reversed to get the reverse order you require